# Condensing a string of time blocks; displaying date ranges

Tags: regex, dart

A user selects a number hours (as [DateTime](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) objects) when making a booking for a rental space.

```
List<DateTime> dateTimeList = getDateTimeList();
```

I convert that list to a presentable string like so:

```
List<String> hourList = List<String>();

for (DateTime dateTime in dateTimeList) {
  String hour = getHour(dateTime, context); // getHour returns e.g. 14:00 or 2pm
  String nextHour = getHour(dateTime.add(Duration(hours: 1)), context);
  hourList.add(hour + " - " + nextHour);
}

hourList.sort();
return hourList.join(", ");
```

Eventually I have the following list:

```
10:00 - 11:00
11:00 - 12:00
15:00 - 16:00
16:00 - 17:00
20:00 - 21:00
```

**Q: How can I condense it, so consecutive blocks are merged? Like so:**

```
10:00 - 12:00
15:00 - 17:00
20:00 - 21:00
```

I've thought of regex replace and various for loops that get to complicated before I finish... and this is not so delicate:

```
string = string.replaceAll("- 01:00, 01:00", "");
string = string.replaceAll("- 02:00, 02:00", "");
string = string.replaceAll("- 03:00, 03:00", "");
etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RegExp` doesn't understand the meaning of the text, just the structure, so you are usually better off parsing the text and handling it with code that understands what is going on.

In this particular case, your textual structure is actually so simple that a `RegExp` can handle it, because you are looking for `- xy:zw, xy:zw` for any digits x, y, z and w.

A `RegExp` mathching that is:

```dart
var repeatedTimeRE = RegExp(r"- (\d\d:\d\d), \1 ");
```

you can then replace do `string = string.replaceAll(repatedTimeRE, "");` to join adjacent time intervals where the second starts at exactly the same time as the first ends.

If your format is not precisely as written, say one o'clock can be written both as "1:00" and "01:00", then textual matching becomes much harder.
If you can have overlapping intervals, then a `RegExp` also can't catch it, say:
`01:00 - 02:00, 01:59 - 02:35`.
A semantic merge function could recognize the overlap and merge anyway, textual matching only really works for strictly equal texts.

Comment: Genius! Thank you. I worked out second expression to take care of the AM PM format:
var repeatedTimeAMPMRegEx = RegExp(r"- ([1-9][0-9]* [AP][M]), \1 ");